# conversion of html to xml format

Tags: dom

```
Converting html to xml. In our project html UI render automatically 
and based on that ui we create xml it is possible to change xml in our 
own style using (html which created dynamically)


note: 1.html not always well formed
      2.In dynamic html how traverse the entire html tree bcoz we didnt know exact structure          
      3.using id i wont be traverse bcoz all are generated automatically.
```

Anyone give simple example which is very useful for ours.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like someone's doing homework...

I would **traverse the dom**. You can google that. It will make sure your result is valid HTML and makes it so you don't have to write any sort of parser.

Here's an old, albeit still useful example:
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/domTree/index.html